# Comparing string to text file

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I am currently working on a code where I add a student to a text file of students and make other calculations. The problem I'm having is I have to sort the new student into the text file so he is in the correct place.

```
StreamWriter changeFile = new StreamWriter("Students.txt", true);
if (pos > 0)
{
    changeFile.Close();
}
else
{
    changeFile.WriteLine(newStudent);
    changeFile.Close();
}

using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("Students.txt"))
{
    string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

So far I have managed to change the text file into a string to compare the 2, but it is in the wrong place. What code would I use to make the StreamWriter compare the newStudent string to the text file so it can put it in the correct order?
P.S. The text file has over 10,000 students in it.

These are the first 5 lines of the text file:

```
students (LIST
(LIST (LIST 'Abbott 'A_____ 'J ) 'NONE 'xxxxx@mail.usi.edu 2.3073320999676614 )
(LIST (LIST 'Abbott 'B_____ 'Y ) 'NONE 'xxxxx@mail.usi.edu 3.1915725161177115 )
(LIST (LIST 'Abbott 'R_____ 'Y ) 'NONE 'xxxxx@mail.usi.edu 3.448215586562192 )
(LIST (LIST 'Abel 'H_____ 'Y ) 'NONE 'xxxxx@mail.usi.edu 3.2517764202656974 )
 ) ) <- this is at the end
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a database if at all possible...

Comment: Why you are restricting yourself to a text-file based solution?

Comment: Please show us an example of your Text File, including any delineators that you are using.

Comment: I just modified the data in your example, not sure what some of the numbers were but the people they are attached to probably would care.

Comment: Actually all of the numbers, emails, and names are fake. So they would care, if they were real haha

Comment: Good, I am glad of that.

Answer (score 2):

Simple method is:

1. Split the string at the line breaks
2. Create a List containing the source lines
3. Add the new student to the list
4. Sort the list
5. Write the list to the file

Alternately:

1. Split the string at the line breaks
2. Create a List containing the source lines
3. Write lines back to the file util you find the position for the new record
4. Write the new record
5. Write the rest of the records.

Or, even better for large files:

1. Read the source file line-by-line
2. Write lines to a temporary destination file
3. When you find the correct place to insert the new record, write it to the dest file.
4. Continue copying lines from source to destination
5. Delete the source file and rename the destination file to take its place.

Comment: I managed to split the lines but I am unable to make it into a list

Comment: Simple.  `var lines = stringFromFile.Split(...).ToList();`.  You'll also need to add a using statement for the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text file contains one student per line, you could read the text file into a list of strings, then add the new student then sort it and write it back to the file.

```
var allStudents = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("Students.txt"));
allStudents.Add(newStudent);
allStudents.Sort(allStudents);
File.WriteLines("Students.txt", allStudents);
```

This is inefficient because every time it reads and writes the whole file. If you have a choice, consider using a database like others have suggested.

EDIT:

Since the first line of your file is not a student, you should remove it before sorting and re-add it later.

You can remove that line like this:

```
var line = allStudents[0];
allStudents.RemoveAt(0);
```

And re-add it like this:

```
allStudents.Insert(0, line);
```

Comment: I managed to make it work, but I can only run it once, whenever it adds the line 0 back, it puts an empty line after it which causes it to mess up on the second run

Comment: Oh and at the end of the code there is  ) ), do you know how I would be able to remove that? I can just write it back in

Comment: To fix the empty line, change `var line = allStudents[0];` to `var line = allStudents[0].Trim();`  To remove the last line, do: `var lastLine = allStudents[allStudents.Count - 1].Trim();` To add the last line back, do: `allStudents.Add(lastLine);`

Comment: I can't get that last part. When I run it, I check the text file and that last part always cuts into the rest of the code

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What does "cuts into the rest of the code" mean? And what does "check the text file" mean? You are supposed to remove the first line and the last line before sorting the list. Then add them both back before saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
var Students = File.ReadAllText("Students.txt").Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList().Union(new string[] { newStudent }).ToList().Sort();
File.WriteAllLines("Students.txt", Students);
```

might work for you